# How to use static files with Custom Web Component

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, native-web-component

I have created a web component, uploaded it to npm, and imported it into another project.

I use webpack to bundle all of the code used within the web component, which creates a bundle file (in my case `index.js`).

This is the structure of my dist folder:

```
/dist
  /static
    /images
    /fonts
  index.js
```

Everything works, except loading images or fonts (static files). How can this issue be overcome? I have just added the static files to a public github repo at the moment, and load them from there. But I do not think this is the right way to do it.

I guess if the images are not that large, they can be converted into base64 and just bundled with the rest of the code?

Any thoughts

Found a similar question [Paths in Web Components are Relative to Root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33454910/paths-in-web-components-are-relative-to-root).

> The webcomponent specification defines that URLs are always relative
> to the main document. This, of course, breaks web component
> encapsulation, as you rightly concluded. In other words, the
> specification is buggy, and lots of people are complaining about it.

Comment: This not Web Component related; this is about handling external files for a Web site. You put them someplace and you have to get the pathnames right.

Comment: Yeah totally. But should a web component not encapsulate everything it needs? Like if there are icons, etc that the web-component uses. The persons importing it should not really have to care about the static file stuff.

Comment: Then do something else besides static files.

Comment: You should add post install script, which copies the images to app public folder, and component should always looks from public folder,
for example - example.com/images/  <--
and in component you can look from images/

Comment: Use es modules and `import.meta.url` so your component knows its import path to properly load assets.